# combinatorial question (sum of numbers without permutation)

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I am having trouble with some combinatorial question. Its not my field and  the question is difficult for me.

I've asked related  question before, [combinatorial question (sum of numbers)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110055/25121) but it turned out that I formulated it wrong. But it was interesting problem any way. Thank you very much for the help!

My real question is:
Given numbers $r$ and $m$. 
Let $m_1,..., m_{{2r}}$ be numbers such that $m_i \in \{0, 1, ..., 2m\}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{2r}m_i=2m$.

Find number of ways choosing $m_1,...,m_{2r}$, such that sum of any $r$ of them will be odd.

I was trying to calculate number of repetitions (order is not important) and then just subtract it from the result  in the question 'combinatorial question (sum of numbers)'. But it seems I have to use different procedure.

Thank you.

Comment: The condition, "the sum of any $r$ of them will be odd," is equivalent to "$r$ is odd, and $m_1,\dots,m_{2r}$ are all odd".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is clear that each $m_i$ will have to be odd and so $r$ will also have to be odd.  So you want the number of compositions of $2m$ into $2r$ odd numbers.

Consider adding $1$ to each of them: you now want the  number of compositions of $2m+2r$ into $2r$ positive even numbers.

This is the same as the number of compositions of $m+r$ into $2r$ positive integers.  This is ${m+r-1 \choose 2r-1}$. You need $m \ge r$ to have any possibilities.

But if order does not matter, you want the number of partitions of $m+r$ into $2r$ positive integers.  There is not a simple formula though you can use generating functions or something like [my Java applet](http://www.se16.info/js/partitions.htm).

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not familiar with generating functions. Where I can find enough information about these functions  to solve my problem?

Comment: A good way of learning about [generating functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) would be to read Herbert S. Wilf's [generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html).  In this particular case, I think you want the coefficient of $x^m$ in the expansion of $$\frac{x^r}{\prod_{j=1}^{2r} \left(1-x^j\right)}.$$ Also look at [OEIS A008284](http://oeis.org/A008284)